# Find and Move Command in Terminal

Tags: find, mv

I have used this command mentioned below to find the files and move it in a folder:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -name "Screen*.png" -exec mv ./ScreenShot/ {} +
```

This is showing this error:

```
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
```

Comment: What Unix are you using?

Comment: Using Mac Terminal

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
mv -t dest {} +
```

or

```
mv {} dest
```

Comment: I think the last one is meant to be `mv {} dest \;`, right?

Comment: @Quasímodo those are just excerpts highlighting the issue to be prefixed and suffixed appropriately

Comment: I used "mv -t dest {} +" as well. It is giving same error

Comment: When I use -t it is showing "Illegal option -- t"

Comment: I got the answer.
I used this command and it works

find . -type f -name "Screen*.png" -exec mv {} ScreenShot/ \;